# Adding the values of numbers in lists? (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and I'm not sure how to do this. I have the following list:

```
marbles_in_bucket = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And I want to add, say, the value of index 1 to the value of index 2 to get 2. I tried to do this by writing `marbles_in_bucket[1 + 2]` but I got `IndexError: list index out of range`. How would I go about this?

Comment: `marbles_in_bucket[1] + marbles_in_bucket[2]`

Comment: you might want to go through some Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: also, your example would not return an IndexError because `marbles_in_bucket[1 + 2]` = `marbles_in_bucket[3]` which exists since your list is of length 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
> marbles_in_bucket[1] + marbles_in_bucket[2]
2
```

You can also index with ranges like:

```
> sum(marbles_in_bucket[1:3])  # the end index is exclusive
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should do it.

```
marbles_in_bucket[1] + marbles_in_bucket[2]
```

If you are running that in a loop and iterating till the end you may need to check that you don't overrun the list.